# Adding a class on a specific div created with a map

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So here is my component:

```
import React, { MouseEvent, useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './css/GameAnswers.css';

type Answers = {
    arrayAnswers: Array<string>,
    correctAnswer: string
}

function GameAnswers(props: Answers)
{
    const [buttonClass, setClass] = useState('');
    function submitAnswer(e: MouseEvent)
    {
        if((e.target as HTMLInputElement).getAttribute('data-key') === props.correctAnswer)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            setClass("btn-success");
            return;
        }
        setClass("btn-danger");
    }

    return (
        <div className="game-answers">
            {props.arrayAnswers.map(function(answer){
                    return <Button className={`game-answer ${buttonClass}`} data-key={answer} onClick={submitAnswer}>{answer}</Button>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default GameAnswers;
```

and here's how I render it:

```
<GameAnswers arrayAnswers={['Yes', 'No']} correctAnswer="Yes"/>
```

when the user presses on Yes, I want to add the class "btn-success" to the button with Yes. When the user presses on No, I want to add the class "btn-danger" to the button with No.

How can I do that while still using map? (I might have multiple buttons in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this a little differently:

1. Use a [`ToggleButtonGroup`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button-props) as this will get you the multiple choice behavior out of the box.
2. Use the `variant` property set the look and feel, rather than manually toggling CSS classes

Below an alternate version of your code with the above suggestions. Check out the link below for a live demo of this version.

### [Click here for a Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/69713920-adding-a-class-on-a-specific-div-created-with-a-map-3b8fx?file=/src/GameAnswers.tsx)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from "react-bootstrap";

type Answers = {
  arrayAnswers: Array<string>;
  correctAnswer: string;
};

const GameAnswers: React.FC<Answers> = ({ arrayAnswers, correctAnswer }) => {
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");

  const handleAnswerChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    setSelectedAnswer(e.currentTarget.value);

  const determineButtonVariant = (answer: string) => {
    if (answer !== selectedAnswer) {
      return "primary";
    } else if (answer === correctAnswer) {
      return "success";
    } else {
      return "danger";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="game-answers">
      <ToggleButtonGroup name="answers">
        {arrayAnswers.map(function (answer) {
          return (
            <ToggleButton
              id={answer}
              value={answer}
              onChange={handleAnswerChange}
              variant={determineButtonVariant(answer)}
            >
              {answer}
            </ToggleButton>
          );
        })}
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameAnswers;
```

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow. If it works, I will accept it :)

Comment: Would you mind explaining the difference between React.FC and a normal function component? :)

Comment: `React.FC` is a shorthand for `React.FunctionComponent` if that's what you mean. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L544

Answer (score 0):

This works for me can you try?
(If there are typescript errors, you need to fix it.)

```
import ButtonWrapper from "./ButtonWrapper ";

type Answers = {
  arrayAnswers: Array<string>;
  correctAnswer: string;
};

function GameAnswers(props: Answers) {
  return (
    <div className="game-answers">
      {props.arrayAnswers.map(function (answer, index) {
        return (
          <ButtonWrapper
            key={index}
            answer={answer}
            correctAnswer={props.correctAnswer}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ButtonWrapper/index.js

```
type Props= {
  answer: string;
  correctAnswer: string;
};

function ButtonWrapper(props: Props) {
  const [customClass, setCustomClass] = useState("");

  return (
    <Button 
      className={`game-answer ${customClass}`}
      onClick={() => {
        if (props.answer === props.correctAnswer) {
          setCustomClass("btn-success");
        } else {
          setCustomClass("btn-danger");
        }
      }}
    >
      {props.answer}
    </Button >
  );
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Both of the buttons are red at the beginning, and they both change colors when I click on one.

Comment: Yes, my fault... edited my answer.